# Is there a way to get the widgettree of a pumped Widget while testing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this TestWidget:

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Io sono Raoul'),
          ),
        ),
        OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const ColoredBox(color: Colors.red),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and in my Test i try to get the WidgetTree:

```
void main() {
  Future<void> pumpWidget(WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: TestWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  testWidgets('description', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await pumpWidget(tester);
    
    final widgettree = ?

    expect(find.byType(Center), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

I tried find.byWidgetPredicate but i only get the location of TestWidget not the widgets inside of it

WidgetsBinding.instance.renderViewElement!.widget; gets me the MaterialApp but when i go down the tree i only get the location again

Comment: maybe you just want to find by text `Io sono Raoul`

Comment: but i try to get the whole tree not just the text